# python: AttributeError: 'ZAxis' object has no attribute '_set_scale'

Tags: python, macos, 3d, matplotlib

I recently updated to OS X Maverics and as one of the results it broke my python matplotlib 3D plotting. For example when I run this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nacho/Documents/Proyecto/codigo/RLS/run_rls.py", line 89, in <module>
    n_plot([bunch.ff_weighted_estimation_error for bunch in rls.rls_bunchs], 'Peso')
  File "/Users/nacho/Documents/Proyecto/codigo/RLS/run_rls.py", line 43, in n_plot
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1066, in gca
    return self.add_subplot(111, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/figure.py", line 789, in add_subplot
    a = subplot_class_factory(projection_class)(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axes.py", line 8457, in __init__
    self._axes_class.__init__(self, fig, self.figbox, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 91, in __init__
    *args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axes.py", line 463, in __init__
    self.cla()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 1040, in cla
    self.zaxis._set_scale('linear')
AttributeError: 'ZAxis' object has no attribute '_set_scale'
```

I'm running Python 2.7.5, and matplotlib 1.3.1.

Comment: are you sure your running the copy of matplotlib you think you are running?  It looks like the core bits (`figure.py` etc) are coming from `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/` and your mplot3D is coming from `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`.  My guess is that you have ended up using a mixed version of mpl due to apple screwing with your paths on the upgrade.

Comment: Yes that was the problem, thanks tcaswell.